# Bundler::GemfileNotFound whenever I try to run bundle install

Tags: ruby, bundler

I'm working in kali-linux (a linux distro witch is the continuation of Back-Track, based in Ubuntu, just that now is based on Debian wheezy) for some penetration testing. Everything was working just fine, until I decided to update my systems tools. Now whenever I try to run a tool based on ruby, it trows me:

```
Could not find gem 'ruby-progressbar (>= 1.1.0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I proceed to run `bundle install` but then it comes with `Bundler::GemfileNotFound` error.

Kali use by default ruby, for using gems. The software don't 'require' any other package but ruby seems not-fully-configured/installed for the problem at hand.

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i486-linux]
$ rvm
bash: rvm: command not found
$ rbenv
bash: rbenv: command not found
```

Comment: `ruby -v` is a slightly simpler way to check the ruby version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that for some weird motive Ruby didn't detected that `bundler` was installed, although the package manager says so.

```
$ apt-cache policy bundler
  bundler:
Installed: 1.3.5-2
Candidate: 1.3.5-2
$ bundle --version
Bundler::GemfileNotFound
```

I simply run `gem install bundler` then `bundler install` as root in the tool root path and everything works as charm.

Answer (score 20):

I faced the same problem when I was trying to `bundle install` without realizing that I was not in the project directory. Make sure you're in the current project directory.

Comment: Lord, I always thought a bundle is a bundle. not depending on anything. And now i moved to my app dir and it was fine. LOL

Answer (score 3):

to avoid this error you should be at the root of your application and create GemFile and specify all gems needed in there, and run bundle install

Comment: I think that that was what I did at the end, check my answer.

Comment: @SachinSingh is correct.  Although this worked, I would highly recommend using a ruby version manager and then install bundler against a given version of ruby.  YOu will have a nightmare when you want to install another version of ruby.

Comment: @MattDressel I know that you are giving me a good advice, but take into account that I ultimately don't develop for Ruby, I just want to use the end tools (although seems an interesting language).

Answer (score 0):

Do you use `rvm` or `rbenv`?  If so, make sure you are using a particular ruby version.

For rvm, `rvm list` and look for an indication next to your ruby version.  If the correct one is not listed, run `rvm install x.y.z`.  If the correct one is not selected, run `rvm use x.y.z`

If you want to segregate your gems for a given project, create a `gemset`.  Otherwise, you should be good to go.

Run `gem install bundler`.  You should not have to do this as sudo.  This will install bundler in either the Default rvm gemset, or the selected gemset.

Bundler should now be available and can be run using `bundle`. This is the same as `bundle install`.

Comment: @Braiam You definitely want to use a ruby version manager, or you are going to have continued nightmares.  I typically use `rvm`, but I know that `rbenv` is also popular.

Comment: @Braiam Additionally, you can add `BUNDLE_GEMFILE` as an environment variable that points to an arbitrary Gemfile path.

Comment: I know is a helpful answer as is. But take into account that the tools that wants to use Ruby are installed as root (and some of them won't run if is not as root) so, I was sure the use of sudo was mandatory, there's a way to revert this and check?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo ln -s /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/bundle /bin/bundle
sudo ln -s /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/bundler /bin/bundler
```

Worked for me in debian.